# Самоподгрузка страницы с через js в обход php?

Tags: php, javascript

Возможно ли сделать подгрузку новых постов на статическом сайте (используя Jekyll в довесок) без php, а через js?
Под подгрузкой подразумеваю добавление в дом-дерево новых постов или изображений, как, например, реализовано это в инстаграмм при достижении конца страницы - подгружается новая пачка фоток.

Comment: Возможно. Ajax.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Вам подойдет jQuery.load. Для совершения ajax запросов не требуется иметь PHP сервер, подойдет любой сервер в том числе и просто выдающий статику, главное чтобы статика и динамический контент принадлежали одному домену(либо нужно знать и уметь как совладать с CORS).

```
$('#result').load('ajax/test.html');
```

Подробнее можно почтитать тут http://ruseller.com/jquery.php?id=16 или в официальной справке.

Comment: Благодарю за информацию!